# write ECONNRESET error during expo build:android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm pretty new to react-native and expo and I'm trying to get a standalone app to publish on the play store. When I run the command `expo build:android` I get an error saying "write ECONNRESET" and it just stops.

```
expo build:android
Checking if there is a build in progress...


? Would you like to upload a keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us handle it! :)
 false
Publishing to channel 'default'...
Building iOS bundle
Building Android bundle
Analyzing assets
Uploading assets
No assets changed, skipped.
Processing asset bundle patterns:
- C:\Users\Srujan Deshpande\Desktop\Klashning\EasylibStuff\Projectv3\**\*
Uploading JavaScript bundles
write ECONNRESET
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Comment: This issue only occurred on Windows. The same code worked perfectly on Linux.